# How to calculate players score with php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a json string with players statistics and I want to get total player score with that player name here is an example of the json

```
<code>{
"Players": [
    {
        "playerId": 1,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 10
        "game_type": "action"

    },
    {
        "playerId": 2,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 120
        "game_type": "action"
    },
    {
        "playerId": 1,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 233
        "game_type": "action"
    },
    {
        "playerId": "n",
        "player_name": "Player n",
        "player_score": "n"
    }
   ]
  }

</code>
```

In this example I need to find player 1 for example and calculate all points 
so this is what it should be right player 1 has 233 points + 10 points = 243 points, $player_name => $totalpoints;

I've trying with loops to do that but with no success.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, IMHO it might be better to leave this to the backend. And to be a bit helpful, use an `each` over that array

Comment: Use `json_decode` then run a loop..most likely

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you! ***UPDATED***

Cheers Mario

```
$json  = '[{"playerId": 1,"player_name": "Player 1","player_score": 10},   {"playerId": 2,"player_name": "Player 1","player_score": 20},{"playerId":  1,"player_name": "Player 1","player_score": 233},{"playerId": "3","player_name": "Player 3","player_score": "3"}]';
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
$totalcount = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   if (!empty($totalcount[$value['playerId']])) {
      $totalcount[$value['playerId']] += $value['player_score'];
   }
   else
   {
    array_push($totalcount, $value['playerId'],$value['player_score'] );
   }
}
foreach ($totalcount as $key => $value) {
echo "Player ".$key." total=".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, how is possible to use without hard coding playerId ?

Comment: Do you want to get back an array with all of them done? and each player with a summed total?

Comment: Updated the code with a summed array output of the players values

Answer (score 1):

Try this. By using this you can get the result as you want.

```
$player_array = json_decode($json_string); // put your json string variable

$palyer_array_total = array();
foreach($player_array as $player){
        $palyer_array_total[$player['playerId']]['name'] = $player['player_name'];
        if(isset($palyer_array_total[$player['playerId']]['total_score'])){
            $palyer_array_total[$player['playerId']]['total_score'] = $palyer_array_total[$player['playerId']]['total_score']+$player['player_score'];
        }else{
            $palyer_array_total[$player['playerId']]['total_score'] = $player['player_score'];
        }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($palyer_array_total);
```

Comment: Hey Amit, thanks, its saying that total_score is not defined

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amit, I've added a parameter called "Game type" how can I group users based on game type   {
        "playerId": 1, "game_type": "action", 
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 10
    },

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and then add them.. let me suppose the array name is `$players`, then..

```
$total_score = 0;
foreach($players as $key=>$value)
{
  if($value['player_name']=='player1')
  {
    $total_score +=$value['player_score'];
  }
}
echo "PLAYER's TOTAL SCORE = ".$total_score;
```

EDIT:

This looks like JSON code.. so first decode it using `json_decode`

Comment: Hey phpfresher is that possible not to harcode 'player1' ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
//Convert json to php array
$listPlayers = json_decode({
"Players": [
    {
        "playerId": 1,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 10
    },
    {
        "playerId": 2,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 120
    },
    {
        "playerId": 1,
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_score": 233
    },
    {
        "playerId": "n",
        "player_name": "Player n",
        "player_score": "n"
    }
   ]
  });

//Sum score for each player id
$totalByPlayers = array();
foreach($listPlayers as $player)
{
    //If player doesnt exists yet, we create it
    if(false === isset($totalByPlayers[$player['playerId']]))
    {
        $totalByPlayers[$player['playerId']] = 0;
    }

    $totalByPlayers[$player['playerId']] += $player['player_score'];
}

//Then for score of player one :
echo $totalByPlayers[1];
```